# link_to not including object's ID in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added a method inside of an existing Rails controller (reports_controller) to handle a specific action that is beyond the basic scope of REST. Let's call that action 'detail':

```
def detail

@report = Report.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @report }
end
```

end

I added the appropriate layout page (detail.html.erb) and routing to make sure that I can access the page from anywhere. This is how my route looks like:

```
  map.connect "reports/:action", :controller => 'reports', :action => /[a-z]+/i
```

Right now I'm able to access any of the detail pages. An example page would look like this: http://127.0.0.1:3000/reports/detail/8

Now, I'm trying to create a link from the main Report index page to the detail pages, but when using the code below:

```
<%= link_to "Details", {:controller => "reports", :action => "detail", :id => @report }, {:title => "see details for this report"} %>
```

The link that is created does not include the report's ID on it an looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/reports/detail
```

Any idea of what's wrong with what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [:member](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
map.resources :reports, :member => { :detail => :get }
```

Using `link_to`:

```
link_to "Detail", detail_report_path(@report)
```

Comment: Didn't work either. I have created the URL manually, that's the only thing working at this point...

Comment: ah, thanks for that! Now the error seems different and seems to relate to my route. I provided only the line on my original question, plus your suggestion (:member). This is the error: <pre>detail_report_url failed to generate from {:action=>"detail", :controller=>"reports"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["reports", :id, "detail"] - are they all satisfied?</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, maybe?
Try no comma right after @report

Comment: hi, that was a typo while typing the question. even without it the same problem happens